# Need help on more of a structure of files dealing with NSMutableAttributed strings

Tags: ios

So this is more of a structure of things than anything and maybe someone can provide some insight on it. So what I am looking at doing is when a user hits a `UISearchBar` I have created a `UIView` that pops up and presents a `UITableview`. In this `tableView` each cell has a string where the first word in the string is bold: eg. (**status:** customer is a new customer) - the 'customer is a new customer' is light gray and the word 'status' is bold black.

There are roughly 6 different parameters a user can select. What this is for is to aid in searching through a database faster. Basically what I'm trying to see if someone can help point me in the right direction on would it be better to just create an array that is hard coded with all the strings in it and then do the `NSMutableAttributed` string part on the fly and then populate the `tableView` with it or create some file that has this information in it already and I just reference the file to populate the `tableView`. Again, these strings are constant and they do not change, they are helpers to kind of aid the user into searching things faster without them actually having to type out something. Any advice on this would be appreciated and hopefully I explained what I'm trying to do well enough to get my point across.

Comment: You can use HTML so `<b>status:</b> customer is a new customer` for each of them, or use an object/struct with a property title/param, and another one "desc" for description which holds "customer is a new customer", and add bold/normal for each one constructing a NSAttributedString, or use two labels.

Comment: So what you are saying for the struct format as I honestly have not used the HTML format before in swift/ios so I'm going to reference the struct at the moment. But within the struct you are saying doing something like:

`let title = "status:"`
`let description = "customer is a new customer"`

and then in the other file where I use that struct..setup a new string that is a NSAttributedString where I bold the title and then append or add the description to it from the struct and then build the cell off of that?

Comment: Please don't hand-wave. Don't _describe_ your code. _Show_ it. Show the data we're talking about, and what you're doing that needs to "faster".